# When trying to generate random Unicode, Syntax Error "Illegal" token

Tags: javascript, unicode

When trying to make a random Unicode (not from all of the unicodes, just the numbered ones) I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

When using this code:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

// Error line:
var randUnicode = ('\u' + getRandomInt(1000, 9999).toString());
```

This is probably because javascript see the `\u` as a trigger of Unicode, but expects something after it.

How would I make random Unicode characters between 1000 and 9999?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var randUnicode =  String.fromCharCode("0x" + getRandomInt(1000, 9999).toString()) ;

Comment: This generates a random *code point* in the *hexadecimal* range 1000...9999. It is unclear what “between 1000 and 9999” means in the question. But it clearly asks for a *character*. There is a large number of reserved code points (not assigned to any character) in the range, whether decimal or hexadecimal.

Comment: There's no need to convert to string and back just for hex.  Try: `String.fromCharCode(0x1000, 0x9999))`